# Angular 2 Unit testing with 3rd party components

Tags: unit-testing, angular, primeng

I'm trying to write a unit test for my component which has a [PrimeNG](http://www.primefaces.org/primeng/) piechart directive in it. PrimeNG uses [Chart.js](https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/Chart.js/1.0.2/Chart.min.js) which is included in my `index.html` and I've added it to my `files` list in the test config. When I execute my test it says `Can't find variable: Chart`. If I remove the 3rd party component from my template the test passes. What is the proper way to create a unit test with a 3rd party component?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In addition to include your files, I think that you also need to configure them into the SystemJS configuration:

- If you execute your test from an HTML page, define this directly in `System.config` in this page.
- If you execute your test using Karma, extend `System.config` in the `karma-test-shim.js` file.

Comment: Well that was quick. I was trying to add to to my System.config, but not at the correct place. The key was the `execute your test from an HTML page`. :D Now it is working. Thanks!